# planning for graphite components for big cassandra cluster monitoring

Tags: cassandra, monitoring, graphite

I am planning to setup a 80 nodes cassandra cluster (current version 2.1 but will upgrade to 3 in future).
I have gone though http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html which has list of tools that graphite supports.

I want to decide which tools to choose as listener and storage so that it could scale.

As a listener should i use the default carbon or should i choose graphite-ng ?

However as storage component, i am confused that whether default whisper is enough? Or should I look at ohter option (like Influxdata,cynite or some rdms db (postgres/mysql))?

As gui component i have finalized to use grafana for better visulization.

I think datadog + grafana will work fine but datadog is not opensource.So Please suggest an opensource scalable up to 100 cassandra nodes alternative.

Comment: we've found that prometheus + grafana makes for a good combo. 80 nodes is a huge cassandra cluster. why do you have so many? how much data are you monitoring? do you need to keep it all in perpetuity?

Comment: Hi..thanks for the reply. Our plan is to use 50 VMs cassandra nodes for horizontal scale-up. We will apply some filter also on metrics to monitor reduces the load on monitoring server.

Answer (score 1):

I have 35 Cassandra nodes (different clusters) monitored without any problems with graphite + carbon + whisper + grafana. But i have to tell that re-configuring collection and aggregations windows with whisper is a pain.

There's many alternatives today for this job, you can use influxdb (+ telegraf) stack for example.

Also with datadog you don't need grafana, they're also a visualizing platform. I've worked with it some time ago, but they have some misleading names for some metrics in their plugin, and some metrics were just missing. As a pros for this platform, it's really easy to install and use.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Your setup looks similar to us. It would be great if you answer few more queries for 35 nodes cassandra :. 1. how many graphite  nodes you have in case you are using it as cluster ? 2. What is disk space and i/o capacity of your graphite node ? 3. what is retention and resolution you have kept ?

Comment: 1. Running as single node. 2. Space - around 30gb/5 iops :), but saving only relevant metrics. 3. Saving 30 days on 1m resolution

Answer (score 1):

We have a cassandra cluster of 36 nodes in production right now (we had 51 but migrated the instance type since then so we need less C* servers now), monitored using a single graphite server. We are also saving data for 30 days but in a 60s resolution. We excluded the internode metrics (e.g. open connections from a to b) because of the scaling of the metric count, but keep all other. This totals to ~510k metrics, each whisper file being ~500kb in size => ~250GB. iostat tells me, that we have write peaks to ~70k writes/s. This all is done on a single AWS i3.2xlarge instance which include 1.9TB nvme instance storage and 61GB of RAM. To fully utilize the power of the this disk type we increased the number of carbon caches. The cpu usage is very low (<20%) and so is the iowait (<1%).

I guess we could get away with a less beefy machine, but this gives us a lot of headroom for growing the cluster and we are constantly adding new servers. For the monitoring: Be prepared that AWS will terminate these machines more often than others, so backup and restore are more likely a regular operation.

I hope this little insight helped you.

Comment: Thank for the helpful reply. I have one more query why you are running single node graphite and not a graphite cluster of at least 2 nodes  ? Also have you applied any filtering on cassandra metrics ?

Comment: 1. I think it was a cost issue, we forward some of the metrics to another aggregation node and keep them for 2 years. But since the cluster structure is constantly changing, the metrics are not comparable anyway. Also we do nightly backups. 2. As stated above: we filter all internode communication metrics since this wouldn't scale.